# An Inequality with Prime Numbers

Tags: number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers

Let $m\geq 8$ be an integer, and let $q$ be the smallest prime that is greater than $m$. Let $p$ be a prime that satisfies $q\leq p<q^2$, and let $p_0$ be the smallest prime such that $p_0q>p^2$. I would like to show that $(p_0-m)(q-m)\leq p^2-pm$. I have tried some small examples, and the left-hand side seems to be much less than the right-hand side. However, I cannot seem to find a way to prove the inequality in general. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Looking first at the case where $p=q$. It's easy to show that $(p_0-m)(q-m)\leq p^2-pm \Longleftrightarrow m\geq p_0-p$ where $p_0$ is the smallest prime that is larger than $p$. Recall that $p$ is the smallest primes greater than $m$. Thus all we need to show is that for the smallest prime $p$ greater than $m$, the second smallest prime $p_0$ greater than $m$ is no more than $2m$. Which is the same thing as saying that for all $m\geq 8$, there exists two distinct primes $p,p_0$ such that $m<p<p_0<2m$. Not quite sure if this direction helps any.

Comment: Well that's true. There are estimates for the ratios of consecutive primes that one may use to show that $\frac{p_{j+1}}{p_j}<\sqrt{2}$ for all primes $p_j\geq 11$. So, for $m\geq 11$, $p_0<\sqrt{2}p<2m$. Then, it is also clearly true for $m=8,9,10$ with $p=11$ and $p_0=13$.

Comment: Also, we can use Theorem 1 [here](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0907/0907.5232.pdf). And since $2m\geq 16 > 11$ there are at least two primes between $m$ and $2m$.

Comment: And I think it follows that for $p>q$, we have $(p_0-m)(q-m) < (p_0-m)(p-m)$ And if we show that $m\geq p_0-p$ with our constraints on $p,p_0$, then we have shown it in general. That will be the more difficult part. Which I think is that there are at least 1 more prime between $m$ and $2m$ than there is between $q$ and $q^2$. But I don't really know about that.

Comment: Because $p_0q>p^2$ and $p>q$, $p_0$ will have to be a lot larger than $p$. So I don't think $m\geq p_0-p$ holds in general.